# Launch application using background service android

Tags: android, service, triggers, alarm, launch

Needed: Launch application using alarm manager when alarm trigger it launch the application.

Tried:
BroadCast Receiver for receive alarm trigger and launch application but not launching the application.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
  
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Setting Alarm:

```
 public void startAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RestartServiceBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, alarmIntent);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.android.cchhaatt.RestartServiceBroadcastReceiver"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true"
  android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
  android:process=":remote">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: are you able to receive the alarm update but not able to launch the activity?

Comment: there are two issues. one is alarm is not trigger when app is killed or goes on doze mode. 2nd and main issue is when alarm is triggered app is not launched

Comment: Do you really need this `android:process=":remote"`. ?

Comment: no i didn't .I thought this will work to trigger my alarm an help to launch my application'